# Blazor Error 400,ReasonPhrase Bad Request Version: 1.1 System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpHandler

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

Please suggest me. I initial project with Dotnet FrameworkCore6. Create project with
**Hosted** and **Individual**. I try to use **HTTPClient.Get** it's work but i use **HTTPClient.Put,Post,Delete,Patch** i got Error 400. How can i fix it. Now i having 2 project get the same problem.

In blazor page

```
public async Task OnSubmit(AppFolder args)
{
    args.IsDelete = false;
    args.FolderColor = "";
    args.CreatorId = "";

    var httpClient = _factory.CreateClient("public");

    var result = await httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("WeatherForecast",args);
    Console.WriteLine("OnSubmit Debug : "+result);
  
}
```

In WeatherController

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> PostSomethings(AppFolder args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Post Debug"+args);
    return await Task.Run(() => Ok());
}
```

I has bypass authen Program.cs

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("public", client => client.BaseAddress = new 
Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress));
```

I got this Error Message

```
OnSubmit Debug : StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: 
System.Net.Http.BrowserHttpHandler+BrowserHttpContent, Headers:
{
  Date: Sat, 18 Jun 2022 11:58:57 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Type: application/problem+json; charset=utf-8
}
```

Comment: Try to read the content which should give you a better idea of what’s happening. At the minute there’s too many variables in play to deduct what it is. My best guess would be to add the [FromBody] attribute to the “PostSomethings” Appfolder parameter

Comment: @scottdavidwalker I was try follow your recommend but i still get StattusCode 400. OMG

Comment: Post the exact code for AppFolder and the Controller (all `[...]`). Best is always a [mre].

Comment: @รัฐพล.James - You would still get status code of 400 but you'd get an error message as to what the problem was.
In your OnSubmit function, try "await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()" and log it to the console

Comment: @scottdavidwalker Thank you very much. I have try `await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()` too helpful. I going to debug it again and i will show my result after tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best guess:

AppFolder has a required `string Name` property and you leave it `null`.

This can easily happen when nullable reference types is ON.

Comment: I has check from debug AppFolder.FolderName is not null.

Comment: So, no `null`s at all? Do post the class.

Comment: I found null at any property. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Note: Reference types will need to be made nullable if it is possible for it to be null. This needs to be done **even if the field has [JsonIgnore]** This took me 3 days to find out... hope it helps you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [POST], [PUT] and [DELETE] you need to decorate your controllers with those attributes  `[HttpPost] [HttpPut] [HttpDelete]`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all recommend. I has fixed this problem. I have any property **null**
I think `virtual` type  will be not effect with model then in not mind it.But it's the problem.

this is my issue.

```
 public class AppFolder
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FoldName { get; set; }
    public string FolderColor { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AppFile> AppFiles { get; set; }
    public bool IsDelete { get; set; }
    public string CreatorId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

And i fixed it by allow null for AppFiles.

```
public class AppFolder
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FoldName { get; set; }
    public string FolderColor { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<AppFile>? AppFiles { get; set; }
    public bool IsDelete { get; set; }
    public string CreatorId { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime UpdatedDate { get; set; }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

BadRequest also happens when you are passing not filled [Required] fields of model to controller post method

Comment: This resolved my issue, thanks!